# Java Builder Pattern implementation, which one is better?

Tags: java, design-patterns, builder

Looking at Joshua Bloch's way of doing builder pattern in java I have this class:

```
public class NutritionFacts {
  private final int calories;
  private final int fat;
  private final int sodium;

  public static class Builder {

    private int calories = 0;
    private int fat = 0;
    private int sodium = 0;

    public Builder calories(int val)
    { calories = val; return this; }

    public Builder fat(int val)
    { fat = val; return this; }

    public Builder carbohydrate(int val)
    { carbohydrate = val; return this; }

    public Builder sodium(int val)
    { sodium = val; return this; }

    public NutritionFacts build() {
      return new NutritionFacts(this);
    }
  }
  private NutritionFacts(Builder builder) {
    calories = builder.calories;
    fat = builder.fat;
    sodium = builder.sodium;
  }
}
```

which I can invoke this way to instantiate a NutritionFacts object:

```
NutritionFacts cocacola = new NutritionFacts.Builder().calories(140).build()
```

There is also a slight variation where I can have this class:

```
public class NutritionFacts {
      private final int calories;
      private final int fat;
      private final int sodium;

      public static class Builder {

        private int calories = 0;
        private int fat = 0;
        private int sodium = 0;

        private Builder(){
        }

        public Builder calories(int val)
        { calories = val; return this; }

        public Builder fat(int val)
        { fat = val; return this; }

        public Builder carbohydrate(int val)
        { carbohydrate = val; return this; }

        public Builder sodium(int val)
        { sodium = val; return this; }

        public NutritionFacts build() {
          return new NutritionFacts(this);
        }
      }

      public static Builder builder(){
       return new Builder()
      }

      private NutritionFacts(Builder builder) {
        calories = builder.calories;
        fat = builder.fat;
        sodium = builder.sodium;
      }
    }
```

And now I can do this to create an instance of NutritionFacts:

```
NutritionFacts cocacola = NutritionFacts.builder().calories(140).build()
```

What should be the preferred way to apply the builder pattern? Are the two mentioned approaches exactly the same in terms of results (clean, immutability, ecc.). Is anything wrong with second approach?

I'd like to have your expert opinion on this.

Answer (score 1):

The second one is far more common amongst existing code. They are almost entirely the same, so it's hard to argue on basic style for either form, except I guess the second form is both shorter, and is using fewer exotic language features (calling inner constructors is very slightly exotic, I guess). Note that some IDE configs will automatically try to 'help you' by adding: `import com.foo.yourpackage.NutritionFacts.Builder;` at the top and turning your code into: `new Builder().calories(140).build();` which is also not what you want. Also, when perusing the javadoc of the `NutritionFacts` class it may not be obvious how to make one with the first form; whereas if there is an explicit static `builder()` method I'll see that right away.

So that's 3 reasons in favour of the second form and I can't really find anything in favour of the first form, except that the API author has one fewer method to write.

But, that's not an argument either: You can use lombok's [`@Builder`](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder) feature to autogenerate all this stuff. It generates the second form.

Comment: I was ready to upvote this until I got to the Lombok part.  The code in the question is a great example of why Lombok is undesirable:  the methods need documentation explaining what the units of carbs, fat, or sodium are.  And explicit methods can throw IllegalArgumentException if given negative values.  Lombok defeats the entire point of encapsulation.

Comment: You can document the fields, and lombok will copy the docs to the relevant places. You can do arg checking in the constructor; if you prefer IllegalArgumentException right as you call, say, .calories() on the builder (vs. when you call build() to complete the operation), lombok cannot yet do that, but feel free to contribute a good idea on what that should look like instead of throwing the entire concept right out with the bathwater, perhaps.